# Firebase storage image doesn't show

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to let users upload profile pictures and I do this by using html file API.
Below is my code for uploading and showing the profile picture:

```
uploadPic.addEventListener('change',function(evt){
    var file = this.files[0];
    firebase.storage().ref().child(user_uid + "/" + file.name).put(file).then(function(){
        console.log("uploaded to storage");
    }).catch(function(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    });

    firebase.storage().ref().child(user_uid + "/" + file.name).getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
        user.updateProfile({photoURL: url}).then(function(){
            console.log("change success");
        }).catch(function(e){
            console.log(e.message);
        });
    }).catch(function(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    });
});

/*profile pic*/
if(user.photoURL===null){
    profilePic.src = "image/anonymous_big.png";
}else{
    console.log(user.photoURL);
    profilePic.src = user.photoURL;
}
```

Whenever the user changes the file it will upload to firebase storage then downloaded as URL and give the value to user.photoURL.
The picture was uploaded and downloaded successfully, however the profile picture looks like this:
[the profile picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gARBi.png)

If I **console.log(user.photoURL)** and click the url in console it shows the correct picture. I have no idea what went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you exactly get with console.log(user.photoURL);?

Comment: Are you sure that the picture is already uploaded when you call firebase.storage().ref().child(user_uid + "/" + file.name).getDownloadURL()? Because the first put is returning a promise and you shoudl proaly chain the promises.

Comment: It says https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/forumtest-623f8.appspot.com/o/OkRxlV2eWdUIpPevRAvz3oyUaAG3%2Fprofile.png?alt=media&token=0ceb7467-28d6-4b2b-ad3f-fddf89706a1b

Comment: It does show "uploaded to storage" then "change success", but let me try that.

Comment: If it says "permission denied", are you sure that you have correctly configured the Storage access rules?

Comment: Found the problem: I only edited the rules on console so it changed back to default after some time. Thank you!

Comment: @WhakeShark  I will create an answer and if you agree you will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment detailing the error "permission denied", you should double check your Storage access rules.